# (1- 3) Notation in Elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

I'm not sure what `(1- 3)` means in Elisp, as I'm only used to seeing operators, or more appropriately "functions," as the first argument in the list, such as `(- 1 3)`, not following a value, as in `(1- 3)`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1+` and `1-` are function names (so you can use `C-h f` to read about them).

`(1+ n)` returns n + 1.

`(1- n)` returns n - 1.

The latter *can* be confusing to read if you don't know what's going on, granted.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is this the paralleled concept to increment and decrement operators in C++?  It was only confusing because I tried to use (2- 3) and this produced an error, but knowing they are increment and decrement functions, it would make a lot more sense.

Comment: I worded the answer poorly at first. These functions just *return* the result of the calculation, rather than incrementing or decrementing their argument. `cl-incf` and `cl-decf` do that, however.

Comment: Oh ok. Wonder why this exists since (+ 1 2) and (1+ 2) seem to both be equivalent.

Comment: @joe_04_04 `(1+ 2)` is one function that increments by 1 and `+` is a function that adds it's arguments, not only 1.

Comment: @joe_04_04 They exist for much the same reason `++` &c do in C & relatives: compilers were once dumb and it's a common enough operation that the idiom remains useful even once the need for it has gone.